Best method for numerically solving Schrodinger equation for quantum tunneling w/ arbitrary potential
Goal: to compute accurate tunneling probabilities with an arbitrary barrier using numerical solutions to Schrodinger's equation.
Main question: what method is best for generating a robust numerical solution to Schrodinger equation for tunneling through an arbitrary barrier?  A resource link would be great.
Current solution: I have a time-dependent numerical solution already made using a moving Gaussian wave packet toward a potential barrier.
The tunneling probability is computed as $$T_{prob}=\frac{\Sigma\psi_3^2}{\Sigma\psi_1^2}$$ where $\psi_1, \psi_2, \psi_3$ are the wave function in regions 1, 2, and 3.  Region 1 is before the barrier where $V=0$, region 2 is inside the barrier where $E<V$, and region 3 is after the barrier where again $V=0$.
I've discovered, however, that the tunneling probability is dependent on the wavepacket starting position and of course the width $\sigma$ of the Gaussian wave packet. Is there some way to solve this?  Wavepacket broadening is expected in a time-dependent solution like this.
I am just looking for a robust method.  Perhaps I am missing a concept with this simulation, or there is a better method.  The resources I have found almost exclusively focus on bound systems, not tunneling.
Some resources used:
https://arxiv.org/html/2403.13857v1#S3
https://www.reed.edu/physics/faculty/wheeler/documents/Quantum%20Mechanics/Miscellaneous%20Essays/Gaussian%20Wavepackets.pdf

You might want to look at Numerov's method. I remember from my computational physics days this is especially useful for a Schrödinger-type differential equation. I once used it for scattering off an inverted Morse potential, works very well.

I can't recommend the link, but instead of considering TDSE, I would rather solve stationary Schroedinger equation with BC representing a plane wave. Tunneling probability can be then extracted from the transmission coefficient. This will at least solve the problem with the dependence on the wavepacket form.

@E.Anikin  How would I set up boundary conditions for TISE numerically?  I have a solution for this, but get inconsistent results because I am just trying to set $\psi = 0$ at the edges, but this makes it inherently a bound eigenvalue problem, which I am not looking for.  The Eigenvalue shoudl be the kinetic energy of the incoming particle.

I would consider stationary Schroedinger equation instead of solving TDSE:
$$
-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial x^2} = (E - V(x))\psi
$$
For large $|x|$, the solution can be written as
$$
\psi = \begin{cases}
e^{-ikx}, & x < 0\\
ae^{-ikx} + b e^{ikx}, & x > 0,\\
\end{cases}
$$
where reflection and transmission amplitudess are
$t = 1/a$, $r = b/a$. (It is assumed that the particle is falling on the potential from the right.)
Such a solution can be found by considering the Cauchy problem for the stationary Schroedinger equation with the following initial conditions:
$$
\psi(x_0) = 1,
$$
$$
\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial x}(x_0) = -ik,
$$
where $x_0$ is some large negative coordinate away from the scattering region. It is easy to verify that these conditions indeed correspond to a plane wave $e^{-ikx}$. The coefficients $a$ and $b$ can be extracted from the solution at large positive $x$.
Some drawbacks of this method:

The potential should quickly decay away from $x=0$ (ideally, become zero at $|x|$ larger than some $L$)
If the potential is high enough, $\psi(x)$ can grow very rapidly in the classically forbidden region, so numerical difficulties may arise.


And I would assume this tunneling probability should be independent of $x_0$?

It seems like the distance from $x_0$ to the barrier (assuming a square for now) has a large impact on the relative amplitudes of the before and after waves.  Based on my first simulation results.

For a rectangular barrier, it certainly should be independent. There may be dependence, say, for a Gaussian potential, but it vanishes for large $x_0$. But I am also afraid that for the rectangular potential there may be numerical difficulties due to discontinuity of the potential.

I can numerically solve with a rectangular potential, and a coulomb potential and it seems to work fine.  My problem is I'm seeing dependence on the value of $x_0$ as it seems to determine the phase of the incoming wave when it reaches the barrier, which in turn propagates differently through the barrier.  Maybe I have set the problem up incorrectly?

Here's my setup (in Mathematica) ***
V[x_] := Piecewise[{{0, x < 0}, {21, 0 < x <= 4}, {0, x > 4}}]. ***
schr = -1/2 D[[Psi][x], x, x] == (Ee - V[x]) [Psi][x];  ***
bdrs = {[Psi][xmin] == 1, [Psi]'[xmin] == -I k}; ***
psol = NDSolve[{schr, bdrs}, [Psi][x], {x, xmin, xmax},
MaxStepSize -> 0.0001];

Well, everything seems all right. It is strange that the propagation of the wave through barrier depends on the phase. On the left side of the barrier, $\psi$ should be $e^{-ikx}$, so the change in phase should only result in a constant phase multiplier. By the way, what are the constants Ee and k? Could the relation $E = k^2/2$ be not taken into account? Also, do you see the oscillating exponent on the left?

I was calculating the tunneling probability wrong, It looks good now. The oscillations were just from tiny errors in the numerical simulation
